# Outlier detection of time series data in R

Tags: r, detection, outliers

What are the steps needed to detect outliers in business sales data (which means there might be trends and seasonality) in R?

I have learnt about ACF, PACF, residual, ARIMA model (basically, time series analysis and modelling). Can I use this knowledge to help me identify outliers?

Is it also possible to ask R to pinpoint which point of data is outlier?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Should be moved to stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may have a look at the following packages available in R.

The R package [`forecast`](http://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) uses loess decomposition of time series to identify and replace outliers.

The R package [`tsoutliers`](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tsoutliers) implements the [Chen and Liu](http://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1993.10594321) procedure for detection of outliers in time series. A description of the procedure and the implementation is given in the documentation attached to the package. You may also see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104882/detecting-outliers-in-time-series-ls-ao-tc-using-tsoutliers-package-in-r-how/104946#104946).

Comment: `tsclean()` 'Identify and replace outliers and missing values in a time series' http://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/tsclean.html

Comment: `tsoutliers()` 'Identify and replace outliers in a time series' http://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/tsoutliers.html