# time series outlier treatment R (tsibble object)

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, tsibble

Does any one know of a  time series outlier detection and treatment function in the `tsibble` or `fable` packages? Alternatively is there  an R function that can be applied to a `tsibble` object for time series outlier treatment?

I have read this post:
[Outlier detection of time series data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750819/outlier-detection-of-time-series-data-in-r)

It seems `tsclean()`and `tsoutliers()` cannot be used on a `tsibble` object as they request for `ts` data type. 
Any suggestions on how I could find a function similar to those for a `tsibble` object?

Thank you!

Comment: Currently there's no equivalent function in **tsibble**.

Comment: tsibble is still in the early stage, and we focus on the major forecasting functionality at the moment. Maybe other ppl would like to implement outlier detection for a tsibble.